# Use excel formula to count total price increase

Tags: excel-formula

Supposed i have the following table:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>product</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>6/1/2017</td>
        <td>11.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>6/2/2017</td>
        <td>11.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>6/3/2017</td>
        <td>11.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>6/4/2017</td>
        <td>11.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>6/5/2017</td>
        <td>11.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>6/1/2017</td>
        <td>7.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>6/2/2017</td>
        <td>7.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>6/3/2017</td>
        <td>7.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>6/4/2017</td>
        <td>7.6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And i want to generate a table that looks like below. The Product column can be inserted manually. But I want the "Total count of price increase" to be generated using Excel formula.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Total count of price increase</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to do so? I tried CountIfs with OFFSet but i could not figure out how to compare with the previous day's price.

Answer (score 1):

This formula works if your first table's data is already sorted by product. Enter this into `Sheet2!B2` and fill down:

```
B2:
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100 = A2) * (Sheet1!$A$3:$A$101 = A2)*
  (Sheet1!$C$3:$C$101 > Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100))
```